# {@link } to an module member in TypeScript in VS Code

Tags: typescript, documentation, jsdoc

VS Code recognise the `{@link}` JSDoc syntax in TypeScript, but I am not sure how to refer to a member in the current module.

I have tried

```
{@link Name}
{@link .Name}
{@link #Name}
{@link moduleName.Name}
{@link moduleName#Name}
```

And VS Code always say "no definition found for Name".

The [typedoc](http://typedoc.org/) project has no info on this either.

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
{@link module:nameOfModule}
```

Ex. if I wanted to link to a module I have called Foo do the following

```
{@link module:Foo}
```

Comment: This definitely does not work with typedoc 0.23.15